# Unable to login while able to access without login

Tags: 6

I am having a strange problem with my drupal website where site is working and anybody is able to surf it properly however the moment I try to login using my admin or account it shows offline message given below. What could be the reason

+++++++++++++
Site off-line

The site is currently not available due to technical problems. Please try again later. Thank you for your understanding.

If you are the maintainer of this site, please check your database settings in the settings.php file and ensure that your hosting provider's database server is running. For more help, see the handbook, or contact your hosting provider.

Comment: Even if site is offline you can able to login by navigating to /user/login page...

Comment: site is working fine and I am able to go to user/login page but the moment I login sites shows offline page

Comment: Did you manage to resolve the issue? If yes, then how?

Answer (score 0):

As you can not login from in your site the only way to do something is from database end, if you have access to database try doing this to come out of this mess up:

Try to empty the sessions and the cache tables. Not DELETE! Empty them.
then see if you can login from http://www.yoursite.com/?q=user

Or look if your site is in maintenance mode if it is the follow instructions given here: https://www.drupal.org/node/276457

Hope above will work for you and you will get your site back to normal.
Good luck!

Comment: Hi emptied sessions and cache but problem remains. I just see a page with offline message and not able to get inside the admin module. Otherwise website is running fine.

Comment: It seems that some connection problem with database look here if it work for you:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/24145/site-off-line-due-to-technical-problems-no-extra-info-in-message-what-cause